# How to show notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I have created an android application for a RSS reader it is working fine .Now i want to show a notification to the user at the time of receiving a new blog or feed

please any one help me how to do that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`NotificationManager`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) class.

Comment: How to use NotificationManager at the time of receiving a new feed or blog

Comment: @Krishna do not expect people to write your code for you. Reading up on documentation and figuring out how to use the APIs is part of developing.

Answer (score 1):

Given answer is good only @Krishna wants to develop a notification. But in his scenario, he needs to tell the user, when they receives an updates. So while you are studying the given link, also remember you should have a mechanism to Broadcast when you receive a notification even when the user is not already open your application. As a hint: you have to provide some services and permissions in Manifest file.

This [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) also explain very well with coding.